# fast, semi-accurate sort in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sorting

I'm going through a huge list of files in Linux, the output of a "find" (directory walk).  I want to sort the list by filename,  but I'd like to begin processing the files as soon as possible.

I don't need the sort to be 100% correct.

How can I do a "partial sort",  that might be off some of the time but will output quickly?

Comment: One approach is to use the input of `find /path -type d` to feed a loop `while read -r dir; do find $dir -type f -maxdepth 1 | sort; done < (find /path -type d)`. That is just an initial thought on the problem

Comment: I believe that `sort` will start doing as much work as it can as soon as data is available. But a “partial sort” is not going to work. (Think about this conceptually.) What you can do is split the data into smaller chunks and sort each chunk individually. If you then merge the sorted chunks again, you have re-invented merge-sort. As a matter of fact, `sort` can do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is StackOverflow, not SuperUser, so an algorithm answer should be enough for you.

Try implementing [HeapSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort). But instead of sorting the full list of names, do the following.

1. Pick a constant `M`. The smaller it is, the more "off" it will be and the "faster" the algorithm will start printing the results. In the limiting case where `M` is equal to the number of all names, it will be an exact sorting algorithm.
2. Load the first `M` elements, `heapify()` them.
3. Take the lowest element from the heap, print it. Put next unsorted name into its place, then do `siftDown()`.
4. Repeat until you run out of unsorted names. Do a standard HeapSort on the elements left in the heap.

This algorithm will be linear in number of names and will start printing the names as soon as the first `M` of them will be read. Step 2 is `O(M) == O(1)`. Step 3 is `O(log M) == O(1)`, it is repeated `O(N)` times, hence total is `O(N)`.

This algorithm will try to keep the large elements in the heap as long as possible while pushing the lowest elements from the heap as quickly as possible. Hence the output will look as if it was almost sorted.

IIRC, a variant of this algorithm is actually what `GNU sort` does before switching to on-disk MergeSort to keep sorted runs of data as long as possible and minimize number of on-disk merges.

Comment: That's very pretty, but won't the heap get clogged up with big values as it progresses, with the result that towards the end of the scan, the output will look more and more like the input? Is there some point at which it makes sense to just flush the heap and restart?

Comment: @rici: The algorithm is essentially heuristic in nature, because there's no exact definition on what kind of mistakes are you willing to accept more. The algorithm above is one variant, an attempt to have something that looks sorted across the whole output. It seems that you'd be more satisfied with the GNU sort variant, which outputs exactly does you suggest: several runs of data that are correctly sorted instead of one long run that has mistakes.